# Argument of type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLDivElement'

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf.js, pdf-viewer, pdflib

i'm trying to make pdf viewer on brower with angular,but i got this error?

[image]

Error:[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: In Angular, you shouldn't be using document.getElementById. Strongly suggest you follow at least an Angular basics course (like the Hero tour on the Angular website).

Answer (score 0):

As SOverflow mates said, it would be necessary that you show your code to be able to help you better.

So, while you add it, I will try to give you a solution based on the data you give, trying to "invent" how I think you have it set up.

1. Try to add a **local Reference** (#viewer) in your HTML:

```
<div #viewer>
   <p>Whatever you have in your code div</p>
</div>
```

2. Get its value with **@ViewChild** in your ts, in the **AfterViewInit** method:

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';


@ViewChild(‘viewer’) viewer!:ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>
// or, depending on your Angular version: @ViewChild(‘viewer’, {static: false}) viewer!:ElementRef<HTMLDivElement> 

 ngAfterViewInit() {

    // Untill ngAftgerViewInit we don't have ViewChild value
    let pdfViewer = new PDFViewer({
      container: this.viewer;
      viewer: this.viewer;
    })

  }
```